# Restore access to Cisco Connect after changing router settings

Tags: wireless-router

I have recently bought Cisco Valet Plus (M20) wireless router (which I recognize now was a mistake, but nevermind). It has two setup options - Cisco Connect software and web-based setup. Cisco Connect software allows changing very small set of settings, web-based setup allows access to almost all settings, *except* settings for guest network. The problem is that when I use web-based setup, Cisco Connect after some changes refuses to talk to the router, so I can't change guest settings anymore (since web interface doesn't allow to change them). It must be because of some config parameter not matching or some password set wrong - but I don't know where Cisco Connect stores them. So, does anybody have any idea how to make Cisco Connect talk to the router again once I changed the settings through the web interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to RE download the cisco connect software (after uninstalling the current install)(links below)

that should get it talking to the router agin.
if that doesn't work you will need to hard reset your router.

to do this you need to

1. unplug everything
2. press and hold the reset button (mine is red and is a little smaller then a #2 pencil eraser) and keep holding it till later
3. plug-in the power while still holding the reset button.
4. keep holding the reset button till the lights flash then stop flashing (I think its about 15 seconds)
5. when the lights look ... different you can let go (I can't remember exactly what they do...but it changes...)
6. uninstall cisco connect software again (if it isn't already uninstalled)
7. re-download (or use a fresh unused copy) and it ***should work***

---

### PC downloads

> for the M10 [save me](http://homedownloads.cisco.com/downloads/utility/CiscoConnect.M10.1.3.11006.1.exe)
>
> for the M20 (the plus modle) [save me](http://homedownloads.cisco.com/downloads/utility/1224659226225/CiscoConnect.M20.1.3.11006.1.exe)

### Mac downloads

> for the M10 [save me](http://homedownloads.cisco.com/downloads/utility/CiscoConnect.M10.1.3.11006.1.dmg)
>
> for the M20 [save me](http://homedownloads.cisco.com/downloads/utility/CiscoConnect.M20.1.3.11006.1.dmg)